# Getting errors when I try to upload my website to the hosting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, error-handling, hosting

I use duplicator to duplicate and upload my wordpress websites to other hostings. I now face with SiteGround hosting, when I upload the zip and the installer.php file Im getting errors, I looked over in error log and this is what im getting:

> [Fri Jan 25 15:51:15.683736 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 5170] [client
>   178.221.215.187:54888] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/scenarea/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>
> (index.html,Index.html,index.shtml,index.php,Index.php,index.phtml,Index.phtml,index.htm,Index.htm,default.htm,Default.htm,default.html,Default.html,home.htm,Home.htm)
>   found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options
>   directive

Is this Apache or .htaccess error? I really never faced this before. I searched over google for similar errors and answers to this, but I had no luck. Help will mean a lot, best wishes!

Comment: i think it means you have to have a file that matches that list in the public_html directory as a 'default file' to serve, when someone hits www.yourdomainname.com

Comment: Yes I read something similar to what you just said, can I do something with it?

Comment: Can you browse the server files (FTP or using a control panel). I bet it's placed your site in a folder within the public_html folder...